# Hive return each user's action list

Tags: sql, hadoop, group-by, hive

I have a hive table t_user_action:

    `uid , timestamp, action
    1, 2016-01-01 12:00, login
    3, 2016-01-01 12:30, login
    1, 2016-01-01 12:05, click
    2, 2016-01-01 13:00, login
    2, 2016-01-01 13:05, logout
    ...`

and I want write a hive sql, return each user's action list. It should be:

    `1, [<2016-01-01 12:00, login>, <2016-01-01 12:05, click>]
    2, [<2016-01-01 13:00, login>, <2016-01-01 13:05, logout>]
    3, [<2016-01-01 12:30, login>]`

how can I get this result through hive sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **collect_set()** function

```
SELECT uid,COLLECT_SET(CONCAT('<',timestamp, ',' ,action,'>'))
FROM t_user
GROUP BY uid
```

Comment: Thank you! this is what I want.